# Get the id and the value of an array generated dynamically

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

I have a dynamically generated array which has data like following:

```
Array
(
    'eti1'=> 'value1'
    'eti5'=> 'value5'
     'eti20'=> 'value20'
    'etin'=> 'valuen'
)
```

this array has been generated in a controller symfony, and then sent to twig to generate a set of input text field dynamically
each textfiel has as id the key of the array (eti..) and the value is the value of array (value ..).
in this example i have 4 value, so i will generated 4 text fields
helps please, hw i get the key and the value of each element in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the key and value in a for loop.

```
{% for id, value in inputs %}
    <input id="{{ id }}" value="{{ value }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

That should do the job for you (assuming your array is called "inputs").